# When segue returns, what method is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a UITableView in a UIPopover; when I tap on a row in the UITableView, I go to a scene (UIView) where I get start and stop times from a UIDatePicker; then using a back button it returns to the calling UITableView, where I want to take the start and stop times and place them in a couple of rows.  I save the results in the AppDelegate so I don't lose them, which probably could be done elsewhere.

Question is: when I dismiss the UIView with datepicker, how can I change the rows in the UITableView when it reappears?  I tried -viewWillAppear, but it never hits it after the UIView is dismissed.  Is there another method that I can use?

Comment: When you say you "go to a scene (UIView)" did you mean UIViewController?

Comment: I guess you could say that... If I'm not wrong, every "scene" that you have when using Storyboards has to have a UIViewController in order to do stuff in that scene.

Comment: You're looking (I think) for delegation. Check out "Using Delegation to Communicate with Other Controllers" in Apple's View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: OK, just thought I'd confirm you weren't doing something weird.  I've just looked at my app, and 

    `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`
and    `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

are both called when a UIController that's on top is dismissed.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor that looks better than the accepted answer to me, why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a notification observer to you UITableView class, e.g.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"UpdateTable" object:self queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}];
```

and then when you dismiss the UIView you send the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateTable" object:nil];
```

Comment: So obvious!  I forgot all about notifications... I'll code it up and get back to you...

Comment: @Filip: probably someone was too quick to judge. Your answer is not in line with question title but it seems it sure does the job. +1

Answer (score 0):

As @Steve Waddicor hasn't added his comment as an answer, and as it is far simpler than the accepted answer, I will post it.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

This is called on the calling TableView when the back button is tapped. Not sure why it is not being called for the original poster.